# Is it possible to use narrow types with Fsharp?

Tags: types, f#

I would think this is something trivial but I have spent some time on it and still, there is no clean way of doing it:

I have a type like:

```
type EngineTypes =
 | Petrol
 | Diesel
 | Kerosene
```

I have a bunch of functions dealing with these just fine.

I would like to make a narrower type and still use the original functions with this new type.

```
type ValidEngineType =
 | Petrol
 | Diesel
```

The only way I could achieve this is by:

```
  type ValidEngineType =
    | Valid of engine : EngineType 
    | NotValid

  let validEngineCheck (engine): ValidEngineType =
    match region with 
    | "petrol" -> Valid EngineType.Petrol
    | "diesel" -> Valid EngineType.Diesel
    | _ -> Invalid
```

Later in code:

```
let myEngine = "petrol"

let checkEngine:Option<EngineType> = 
  match (validEngineCheck myEngine) with
  | Valid engine -> Some engine
  | Invalid -> 
      Console.Error.WriteLine("Unsupported engine: {0}", myEngine);
      None

if checkEngine.IsNone then
  Console.Error.WriteLine("Unsupported engine type")
  Environment.Exit 1

// it is now safe to call this
callingOriginalCode checkEngine.Value
```

Is there an easier way to manage this?

Update1:

In ADA this is called constrained subtype.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Constrained_subtype

Comment: validEngineCheck  appears to have a typo. Also you don't really need a new type here, you could return an Option or (better, IMO) a Choice<EngineTypes,string>, with the string being an error message that includes the invalid text that was passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to partition your engines into valid engines and other engines. That is a perfect task for [active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns). If you have string input as in your code:

```
let (|ValidEngine|_|) (engine: string) =
  match engine with // case-sensitive check here
  | "petrol" -> Some EngineTypes.Petrol
  | "diesel" -> Some EngineTypes.Diesel
  | _ -> None
```

And your code becomes

```
let myEngine = "petrol"
match myEngine with
| ValidEngine engine -> callingOriginalCode engine // it is now safe to call this
| _ ->
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Unsupported engine type")
    Environment.Exit 1
```

As you can see active pattern not only partition engine string into valid and invalid engines, but this partition also has a payload of engine value. So your `callingOriginalCode` function will be called with the original `EngineTypes` parameter, but only when engine type is `Diesel` or `Petrol`.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey, this is an interesting one.

Comment: @Istvan you can of course partition `EngineTypes` values instead of strings, I just wanted to show how your sample code will look like

Comment: Yes, this absolutely works and I think this is the shortest and best solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is deal with a sum type in arbitrary way over subsets of value constructors.

You can explicitly model the subsets and embed them in the superset:

```
type ValidEngineTypes = Petrol | Diesel
type EngineType = Valid of ValidEngineTypes | Kerosene
```

(you can do something similar with OO interface and inheritance, but lets put that on one side).

If the combinations are largely arbitrary in inconsistent with each other you can model each type explicitly and then create the "sum" type using Choice

```
type Petrol = Petrol
type Diesel = Diesel
type Kerosene = Kerosene

type EngineTypes = Choice<Petrol,Diesel,Kerosene>
type ValidEngineTypes = Choice<Petrol,Diesel>
```

if you want to define a function on EngineTypes then

```
let foo (engine: EngineTypes) = 
    match engine with
    | Choice1Of3 _petrol -> "petrol"
    | Choice2Of3 _diesel -> "diesel"
    | Choice3Of3 _kerosene -> "kerosene"
```

If you don't like using `ChoiceN<a,...>`
then just do it explicitly using...

```
type EngineTypes = 
    | PetrolEngine of Petrol
    | DieselEngine of Diesel
    | KeroseneEngine of Kerosene

let foo (engine: EngineTypes) = 
    match engine with
    | PetrolEngine _petrol -> "petrol"
    | DieselEngine _diesel -> "diesel"
    | KeroseneEngine _kerosene -> "kerosene"
```

P.S. there are things in here that can be more succinct, or idiomatic, I'm just trying to make it as simple and explicit as I can

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how it works with the functions that take EngineTypes.

Comment: I've ammended it